# Selecting UITableViewCell AccessoryView, separate from selecting row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableview` that I'm displaying some tasks and each row has a checkbox to mark tasks complete or not.

I'm looking to toggle the checkmark when the user taps on the checkbox, and switch to a detailed view when the user taps on the row. The latter is easy, just by using

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

However, I wanted to separate the selection areas, toggling only the checkbox when the `accessoryview` is selected, and going into detailed view only when the rest of the cell is selected. If I add a `UIbutton` inside the `accessoryview`, the user would be selecting the row AND the `UIButton` when they only wanted to hit the checkbox, right?

Also, what if the user was just scrolling through the tableview by dragging along the `accessoryview`? Wouldn't this trigger an action on the `UIButton` on TouchUp?

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about managing accessory taps inside this delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**EDIT:**

You can do something like this for custom accessoryView that responds to `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` Method -

```
BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage   imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
button.frame = frame;
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryView = button;

- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
   NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
   if (indexPath != nil)
  {
     [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
  }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
  [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];

  UITableViewCell *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;

  UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
  [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: How do you get your custom accessory button to call back to the table view's delegate?

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that, sorry for the dumb question and thanks for the help! I'll give that a shot, it sounds like that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @CarlVeazey Good point, the documentation says the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath responds to the disclosure button accessory type, which is not the type I want to use since I want a checkbox.

I can get around this by using the disclosure button for the detailed view, and tapping the rest of the row to toggle a checkmark elsewhere in the row, but that's not what I wanted.

Comment: Yeah see I've wished I could hook into that delegate method for years. @OhhMee if you have the tip on how to do this, don't hold out!

Comment: Yeah, I usually end up doing something like that, although I just handle the tap without the further redirection of faking that it's from the delegate method.